# Expressão regular no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, regex

Eu não sou muito bom em regex mas utilizando o site https://regex101.com consegui gerar uma expressão que aceita:

- Não aceite caracteres especiais
- Pode ter até 5 palavras separadas por whitespace

Segue a regex gerada: `(^\w{0,30}){1}(\s?(\w{0,30})){1,4}`

Estou tentando utilizá-la em uma classe Request como uma Rule regex

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'name' => 'required|max:255|unique:classes,name|regex:/(^\w{0,30}){1}(\s?(\w{0,30})){1,4}/m',
        'description' => 'max:255',

    ];
}
```

Isso não está sendo validado, qualquer coisa que eu entrar no campo 'name' o sistema aceita.

Comment: Já leu o que diz a documentação ? A documentação diz que se está a usar validação de regex pode ter que utilizar um array em vez de separar cada regra com `|`. Eu começava por testar isso. Nota da [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex): "Note: When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character."

Comment: Pois é, eu li isso e fiz a chamada da função validate() por array, mas aconteceu a mesma coisa. Creio que seja problema de sintáxe da regex, pois eu peguei todos os simbolos e coloquei num regex mais simples e funcionou. É essa solução que vai ficar, por enquanto (risos)

Comment: Isso é porque provavelmente a sua regex não está correta. A regex que tem vai validar se tiver 6 palavras por exemplo, pois você não indica que não pode ter mais nada a seguir à 5 palavra. [Veja esta sua regex no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gBZs0P/1). Para corrigir esse pormenor basta adicionar um `$` no fim da regex para indicar que tem de terminar ali e não pode ter mais nada à frente. Agora só você sabe os casos em que a regex está a falhar onde não devia

Comment: Nossa! kkkk era só colocar `$/`no fim da regex

Comment: Obrigado, Isac! 

Como faz pra pontuar tua resposta?

Comment: Eu não respondi logo não dá para pontuar/aceitar, mas posso colocar uma resposta se preferir, para deixar a pergunta finalizada.

Comment: para surtir efeito, tente colocar em "" (aspas duplas)